# What exactly is meant by contact angle between two ovals?

Tags: geometry

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects) wikipedia article, a contact angle $\phi$ is mentioned.

I am unsure if the angle is the [angle between the normal and the x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwpaq.png) or just the angle between the line formed by connecting the centers and the x axis.

In the case of a circle, it doesn't matter, as the line joining the centers is the same as the normal. However, I'm dealing with ovals, where this distinction becomes important.

I've been trying to understand the actual math used in the article to see if that leads me to a conclusion, but I can't fully understand it.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still take the line tangent to the ovals at the point of collision and a line orthogonal to it. In case of the ovals it will no longer be the line connecting the two centers, but it doesn't matter, if the ovals are perfectly stiff and don't deform. The angle between the normal and the $x$ axis will be the contact angle.

To understand why this angle is important, notice that without friction the momentum can only be transferred in the direction normal to the tangent line.